# initialize image background in css using php variable

Tags: php, html, css

I have initialize a variable to fetch from this directory as shown

```
<?php  $imgSrc =  base_url()."decoy/thumbs/".$item["filename"]; ?>
```

now I want to assign the variable to a background url of css code block as shown but it is not displaying the image background

```
<div style="background: url('<?php echo  $imgSrc  ?>') no-repeat;" class="large"></div>
```

can anyone kindly assist me on how I can I achieve the above.

Comment: are you sure your `$imgSrc` is giving you the correct url ?

Comment: What reresult for echo  $imgSrc

Comment: I did something similar to this and it is working perfectly
>>>>> <img class="small" src="<?php echo  $imgSrc  ?>" width="200"/>

Comment: view source of the page and see if imgSrc is output correctly because this should work.  Can you show the rendered html

Comment: which of the rendered html

Comment: Any error like Call to undefined function base_url()  ?

Comment: @Samundra comment was a guide to resolve the problem. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the "imagePath" in place of "imgSrc" so that the image will prompt in backgroud, because in the backroud-url there is no need of absoulte path only relative path will be ok for this.

```
$imgPath = "../decoy/thumbs/".$item["filename"]"; 
<div style="background: url('<?php echo  $imgPath;  ?>') no-repeat;" class="large"></div>
```

Comment: please use this: <?php $imgPath = "../decoy/thumbs/".$item["filename"]; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Follow these easy steps to investigate your problem.
After getting the image

```
<?php  $imgSrc =  base_url()."decoy/thumbs/".$item["filename"]; ?>
```

Verify what was returned to the image variable `<?php echo  $imgSrc; ?>`
That way you will be better placed if you find nothing wrong update your question with the necessary information.

Finally I prefer you use ***string concatenation*** instead change this

```
<div style="background: url('<?php echo  $imgSrc  ?>') no-repeat;" class="large"></div>
```

to

```
   <?php  

    $imgSrc =  base_url()."decoy/thumbs/".$item["filename"]; 
       echo '<div style="background:'.url($imgSrc).' no-repeat;" class="large"></div>';
    ?>
```